# Escape correctly double quotes

Tags: groovy, escaping

I have the following two commands executed inside a pipeline

```
def IMAGE = "url/microservices/currency-converter-search:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
sh "cat task-blueprint.json | jq .containerDefinitions[0].image=${IMAGE} > currency-converter-search-task-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.json"
```

the problem is that I get back an error because the string that I need to save need to be surrounded by `"` double quote in order to be save by `jq`

This is the error I get:

```
[workspace] Running shell script
+ jq .containerDefinitions[0].image=264721266761.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/currency-converter/search:1
error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting $end
.containerDefinitions[0].image=264721266761.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/currency-converter/search:1
                                            ^^^
1 compile error
+ cat task-blueprint.json
cat: write error: Broken pipe
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

and here you can find my file

https://github.com/mazzy89/currency-converter-search/blob/develop/Jenkinsfile#L26

Comment: What is "the string that I need to save"?

Comment: is the IMAGE variable but it needs to be surrounded by double quotes in order to be parsed by jq

Comment: How about you show us exactly what happens, including the exact error message?  It also might help if you were able to add a print statement for "$IMAGE" and also if you put the "sh" command line into a variable and printed that.

Comment: Sure I'm going to post @DavidM.Karr

Comment: @DavidM.Karr updated with further info

Answer (score 2):

Just escaped the quotes

```
...image=\"${IMAGE}\"
```

Comment: your problem must be elsewhere then

Comment: Again, "doesn't work" also doesn't tell us anything.  If it doesn't work, tell us exactly what went wrong, and how it varied from your expectations.

Comment: @tim_yates as you can see the problem is there because I escape correctly double quotes but the result is without double quotes and  instead it should have